# Voltage in an inhomogenous electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage

In a homogenous electric field, we know that the voltage is U=Es. But in an inhomogeneous electric field is there any way to calculate the voltage at some point or between two points?

Comment: Is the inhomogeneous electric field conservative?

Comment: the definition of electric field in terms of potential is **E**=**grad**(V), wher V is the electrostatic potential.
U being Vb-Va (potential difference between 2 points), you just have to integrate the relation above to get what you want. Is that what you're asking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In an arbitrary electrostatic field, the voltage difference between any two points A and B can be calculated as the negative of the line integral of the electric field along any path between the points:

$$V(B)-V(A)=-\int_A^B{\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{\ell}}$$